# Solving system of modular equations

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

Are there techniques for solving the following system of modular equations without having to factor z?

$$
\begin{align}
x_1 y_1 \equiv r \mod M \\
y_0 x_1 + x_0 y_1 \equiv s \mod M \\
x_0 y_0 \equiv t \mod M \\
(x_1 m + x_0)(y_1 m + y_0) \equiv z \mod M 
\end{align}
$$

where $x_0, x_1, y_0, y_1$ are unknowns and $r,s,t,z,m,M$ are known.

Comment: The last equation is redundant provided $$rm^2+sm+t \equiv z$$And if $rm^2+sm+t \not\equiv z$, then the system of equations has no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, the system has solution(s) only in the case when $$rm^2+sm+t  \equiv z$$
and in that case it reduces to the system of 3 equations

$$\begin{align}
x_1 y_1 \equiv r \mod M \tag1\\
y_0 x_1 + x_0 y_1 \equiv s \mod M \tag2\\
x_0 y_0 \equiv t \mod M \tag3\\
\end{align}$$

Multiplying (2) with $w = y_0x_1$ results in a quadratic equation in $w$:

$$w^2 -sw + rt \equiv 0 \tag 4$$

Similarly, multiplying (2) with $v = x_0y_1$ results in a quadratic equation in $v$:

$$v^2 -sv +rt \equiv 0 \tag 5$$

(4) and (5) are the same quadratic equations, and the conditions for $v$ and $w$ are necessary for the system (1)...(3) having a solution.
Yet another necessary condition is

$$vw = rt\tag 6$$

Now knowing all solutions of a quadratic equation mod $M$ is usually same effort like working out the factorization of $M$. For example, knowing all solutions to $x^2\equiv 1$ it's usually easy to get a non-trivial factorization.

Also notice that 4 variables are constrained by just 3 equations, so you may expect "many" (order magnitude of $M$) solutions.  For example, if $u$ is some unit in $\Bbb Z/M\Bbb Z$ and if $(x_0,y_0,x_1,y_1)$ solves the system, then $(x_0u,y_0/u,x_1u,y_1/u)$ also solves the system.

Returning to your question

> Are there techniques for solving the following system of modular equations without having to factor $z$?

I don't really see how factoring $z$ would help in solving the system, in particular because

- Factorizations mod $M$ are highly non-unique, and the number of factorizations is order of magnitude of $M$.  For example, if you have $z=ab$ then for any unit $g$, $z=(ag)(b/g)$ is yet another factorization.
- The equivalent, reduced system doesn't even contain $z$ any more.